# AngularJS Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error, Tried everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Okay first of all I tried searching and did the solution but to no avail

I have tried everything I could. I also added angular resources but the errors doubled so I removed it. Anyways am I missing something? I haven't used angular for a while so this is kinda tricky for me

This is my **app.js**

```
angular.module('chad',['ngRoute','UserManagementController','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','oitozero.ngSweetAlert','appRoutes',"ui.materialize"]);
```

This is my **appRoutes.js**

```
angular.module('appRoutes',[]).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routerProvider,$locationProvider){
$routerProvider

    .when("/chad/index",{
        templateUrl:'index.html',
        controller: 'UserManagementController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}
    );
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

This is my scripts

```
    <link href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="css/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <!-- Custome CSS-->
    <link href="css/custom/custom.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">


    <!-- INCLUDED PLUGIN CSS ON THIS PAGE -->
    <link href="js/plugins/prism/prism.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
          media="screen,projection">
    <link href="css/userManagementCss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="js/plugins/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-utils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/UserManagementController.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<!--materialize js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--prism-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/prism/prism.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/angular-materialize.js"></script>
<!--scrollbar-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<!-- chartist -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<!--plugins.js - Some Specific JS codes for Plugin Settings-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<!--custom-script.js - Add your own theme custom JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom-script.js"></script>
```

Did I missed a script or something?

I'm stuck at this :(

```
angular.js:14328 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SweetAlertProvider <- SweetAlert <- UserManagementController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=SweetAlertProvider%20%3C-%20SweetAlert%20%3C-%20UserManagementController
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4630
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4783)
    at angular.js:4635
    at getService (angular.js:4783)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4808)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4834)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10695)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9572)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8881)
```

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: Try removing the 'UserManagementController' injection in module. I think its not required. You can add it in ng-controller of html page. Use angular.module('appRoutes',[]) or angular.module('chad',[]). Might be because  two different modules.

Comment: Make sure your UserManagementController.js is defined on module 'appRoutes'.

Also try to move the script tags of your app files after all angular core, 3rd party dependency and other plugins are defined.

Showing us your error code might help too.

Comment: You left out name of module in the error. Use angular development version for more verbose error and stack trace output

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: in <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script> try to change to src="libs/angular/angular.js". it will give a better error message

Comment: Okay I found out the error is the 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert' so I removed it but a new error arises. What should I do?

Comment: *"new error arises"* .. error messages are important. People can't guess what they are or where they get thrown

Comment: The new error message is already posted up there

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to inject NgRoute in the appRoutes module

```
angular.module('appRoutes',['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routerProvider,$locationProvider){
$routerProvider

    .when("/chad/index",{
        templateUrl:'index.html',
        controller: 'UserManagementController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}
    );
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: I added 'ngRoute' but didn't do anything. still with the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you messed up in loading your scripts correctly. *The order matters*

1. Your jQuery script is loaded **twice**.

   - Remove the second case: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`
2. Your `app.js` is loaded **before** `materialize` and other plugins, therefore it can't find some of them and fails to inject those plugins into the app.

   - Swap the order ot scripts: `app.js` should come after the last usable script (*possibly after* `sweetalert.min.js` *?*)

Comment: The scripts after the app.js is at the end of the code before </body>

Comment: @Mark you should definitely change the order. If you read the error, `UserManagementController` can't find `SweetAlert` provider, because it is inserted after and not before